# How to copy an article from database in Joomla?

Tags: database, joomla, copy

When I copy a row of ***prefix*_content** table in database, that article is shown in Articles Component in management but not in *featured* page (home).
Except *id* all columns are similar with original article. Notice article is published and my homepage shows *featured* articles.

Comment: Did you mark it as a featured article?

Comment: yes. article is featured. but not show yet in feature page.

Comment: It shows up in the featured view in the administrator? By the way you most definitely cannot just copy the row in #__content, you need to use the API because of all the related changes in other tables that have to be made, in this case including to the featured table as well as to the assets table.  If you want to copy use the API for creating a new article, but use the copied data.

Comment: @Elin 
also all article that copied from row in database not showing in site.
what is asset_id? this column for text display is effective?
*_assets table what does work? Is it really necessary to post the article?

Comment: @Elin Yes it shows up in the featured view in the administrator.

Comment: You need to use the API to make the copy you can't just go to php my admin and do it.  You need to go to the admin, select the article checkbox, do batch, then select copy and what category you want it to go in.

Comment: asst_id is one of the most important fields and you cannot do it by hand in any reasonable way. If you have two rows with the same asset ids you are going to have serious problems.  Why is it that you want to have two copies of this article? That's the real question because it seems very strange to do that.